How can I replace my tab key with AutoHotkey?
My keyboard broke, and some keys are not working. To overcome this situation, I wrote a simple script that makes the letter 'q' act as 'Tab' when I hold down 'Shift':
+q::Send "{Tab}"

The problem is that if I press 'Alt+Shift+Q', it doesn't work as 'Alt+Tab'.
I tried using:
!q::Send "!{Tab}"

but I can only navigate between two windows (I can't hold down 'Alt' and tap 'Q' to navigate). If you know how to solve this, I would appreciate your help.


The Blind mode avoids releasing the modifier keys (Alt, Ctrl,
Shift, and Win) if they started out in the down position...

#Requires AutoHotkey v2

+q::Send "{Tab}"

!q::Send "{Blind}!{Tab}"

!+q::Send "{Blind}+!{Tab}"

